# How to optimize this query to produce many comma spearate data?

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

This is my query:

```
SELECT
   t1.vehicle_id vehicleId,
   GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(t2.vehicle_name)) vehiclename,
   t1.from_state_id fromStateId,
   GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(t3.state_name)) fromState,
   t1.to_state_id toStateId,
   GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(t4.state_name)) toState,
   t1.from_city_id fromCityId,
   GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(t5.city_name)) fromCity,
   t1.to_city_id toCitiesId,
   GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(t6.city_name)) toCities 
FROM
   tbl_vendor_workstations as t1 
   LEFT JOIN
      tbl_vehicles as t2 
      ON find_in_set(t2.id, t1.vehicle_id) 
   Left JOIN
      tbl_states as t3 
      ON find_in_set(t3.id, t1.from_state_id) 
   Left JOIN
      tbl_states as t4 
      ON find_in_set(t4.id, t1.to_state_id) 
   Left JOIN
      tbl_city as t5 
      ON find_in_set(t5.id, t1.from_city_id) 
   Left JOIN
      tbl_city as t6 
      ON find_in_set(t6.id, t1.to_city_id) 
where
group by
   t1.id ";
```

When I execute this query, it runs very slow. Does an alternative way exist to find many coma separate data?

Comment: `where group by`???? Does that really work!?!?!

Comment: Firstly as said by @RiggsFolly your `where group by` is strange. Then, have you tried to set index on your fields?

Comment: I have already set the index with all field still its running slow.and where condtion is where t1.vendor_id=300 and enterprise_user_id=68 group by t1.id

Comment: And exactly how were we supposed to know that? **We are not clairvoyant** Post real code if you want a real answer

Comment: @biswa - can you post the create of the table with some sample data or in http://sqlfiddle.com/ . then i write you a better query with more performance.

Comment: @Bernd Buffen Table1:-tbl_vendor_workstations

Vehicle_id     fromState                       tostate                     
38,39,40        2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10            2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Table2: tbl_vehicles

Id       vehicle_name
38       Taurus-10 wheeler (15/16MT)
39       Trailer-22 MT
40       Trailer-26 MT


Table3:- tbl_states
Id  state_name
2    Andhra Pradesh
3    Arunachal Pradesh
4    Assam
5    Bihar
6   Chandigarh
7   Chhattisgarh


Same as table4:- tbl_city

Comment: @biswa - can you please post it as dump. then i can direct import it. You can use sqlfiddle.com to store it

Comment: table dump on below tables http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3218f5,

Comment: You are using FIND_IN_SET which suggests fields containing comma separated lists in your main table. This is going to render your indexes virtually irrelevant. I would suggest redesigning your tables to remove the comma separated lists (use link tables instead), which would allow indexes to be used effectively and massively help performance (as well as avoiding other issues with comma separated fields).

Comment: t1 desperately needs `INDEX(vendor_id=300, enterprise_user_id)` (in either order).

Comment: `UNIQUE KEY `vehicle` (`vehicle_id`(255),...)` will _not_ work as expected!  (1) 'prefixing' makes indexes virtually useless. (2) the uniqueness check is on only part of the TEXT.  The answer(s) obviate this criticism.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have fields in the tbl_vendor_workstations which consist of comma separated lists of ids. This is a very bad idea. It stops the indexes being used effectively and also means that you have a limit on the list of values to hold for each item (ie, depending on the length of the field you are storing them in).

I would suggest you change your database to use link tables. Each of these would store the id of the row from tbl_vendor_workstations and the (for example) vehicle_id, with 1 row per combination. Hence one tbl_vendor_workstations.id might have dozens of rows on this table. You then join from tbl_vendor_workstations to the link table and then on to the tbl_vehicles to get the details of that vehicle.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_vehicles_link
(
    vendor_workstations_id  INT(11),
    vehicle_id  INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (`vendor_workstations_id`, `vehicle_id`),
    KEY `vehicle_id` (`vehicle_id`),
);
```

Then your SQL would be something like this

```
SELECT t1.vehicle_id vehicleId,
           GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(t2.vehicle_name)) vehiclename,
           t1.from_state_id fromStateId,
           GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(t3.state_name)) fromState,
           t1.to_state_id toStateId,
           GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(t4.state_name)) toState,
           t1.from_city_id fromCityId,
           GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(t5.city_name)) fromCity,
           t1.to_city_id toCitiesId,
           GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(t6.city_name)) toCities 
FROM tbl_vendor_workstations as t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_vehicles_link as tl2    ON tl2.vendor_workstations_id = t1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_vehicles as t2  ON t2.id = tl2.vehicle_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_states as tl3   ON tl3.vendor_workstations_id = t1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_states as t3    ON t3.id = t1.from_state_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_states as tl4   ON tl4.vendor_workstations_id = t1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_states as t4    ON t4.id = t1.to_state_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_city as tl5     ON tl5.vendor_workstations_id = t1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_city as t5      ON t5.id = t1.from_city_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_city as tl6     ON tl6.vendor_workstations_id = t1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_city as t6      ON t6.id = t1.to_city_id
WHERE t1.vendor_id=300 AND enterprise_user_id=68 
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: `tbl_vehicles_link` can be improved on by following these [_many:many table tips_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Comment: @rick thanks for response I have so many data for different id, how can i manage with your process any other way.

Comment: @biswa  More different id fields makes it more certain you need to use link tables such as I have described above.